# VS2010 and MSBuild get different results on combined C++/C# solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, build

I have a big VS2010 solution, which contains a bunch of C# projects. One of those projects consumes a C++ (native, aka unmanaged) library via P/Invoke. To ensure everything builds correctly, I have included said C++ project in the same solution. Now, this is where the problems start.

**In short**: MSBuild mysteriously removes some output files, while VS2010 builds correctly.
.

**The long story**:
Previously (VS2005/2008), I would have utilized the nifty feature called "Project Dependencies". That's the thing that allows you to pick which particular projects a given project depends on, so that the environment makes sure to build those first.

VS2010, however, has moved in the direction of MSBuild, and now project dependencies just plain don't work. They just don't. (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123042/vs2010-project-dependencies) for example)
Now, in order to ensure that my C++ project builds before the one consuming it, I have to "Add a Reference". So I've done that. And everything seems fine.

But then, I go to my command line and fire up MSBuild to build that same solution. And everything builds fine, again. But when I look in the output folder, the C++ project's output is not there!

The MSBuild console output clearly shows that the C++ project has really been built at some point. And I even inserted some "**dir bin\MYPROJNAME.dll**" statements as Post-Build steps into some projects to see if the files are there - **and they are**! [Here](http://apreleva.com/trs/missingdll.png) is a screenshot of the command-line window. Circled in red is the moment of files being there (at the top), and then the moment of files missing (at the bottom).

Another weird thing is that the project, apparently, gets built twice. See the red underline in the screenshot - this is the **second** message about building that same project (the first message, along with all compiler output, was way up the screen).

It really looks like this second building event is what causes the files to be removed: when I disabled building this project at all (through solution properties), it only got built one time, and the files were there in the end. I could have called this a "solution", but then it breaks in the Visual Studio itself: the VS just doesn't build the project.

Another way to fix this is to remove the "Project Reference" from the consuming C# project. Then MSBuild will only build the C++ project once, and the files will be there. But then it breaks in yet another place: changes to the C++ project would not trigger a rebuild of the consuming C# project.

**So the question is**: how do I make MSBuild not remove the freaking files?

Comment: Review the platform targets being used in the solution.  That can get pretty mixed up in VS2010, especially if you imported this from an earlier version.  Turn output verbosity to 11 as well to see more of exactly what it is contemplating.  You can take this to connect.microsoft.com but you'll need to better document it.  At least include the project and solution files.

Comment: @Hans, thank you. I have used your advice and run MSBuild with `/v:diag`. This gave me some more insight, but I'm still at a loss. Here is the relevant part of the MSBuild output: http://apreleva.com/trs/missingdll.txt Notice how the 'Build' target is skipped (line 89), because 'previously built successfully'. Yet, all the various 'clean up' targets fail to get skipped. Any ideas?

Comment: Oh, and I must also add that I'm building with `/t:Rebuild`, so the 'clean up' targets are actually correctly executing. It's the 'Build' target that is at fault here: it shouldn't get skipped.

Comment: My be a wild goose chase, but is a 32/64bit mixtures a factor in your target platform, development environment or referenced libraries? VS2010 has been less vocal about these kind of issues than previous versions for me.

Comment: @Kynth, this seems unlikely to me. Yes, my work machine is 64-bit, and while MSBuild is a 64-bit process, VS2010 is 32-bit, which may create an inconsistency. But my build server is a 32-bit machine, so MSBuild runs as a 32-bit process there, but still yields the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short (a bit of a hack) answer to the question:

You had the dir in the PostBuildEvents. If you add an attrib +r it will not remove your files:

```
<Exec Command="attrib +r $(TargetPath)"/>
```

(Where TargetPath should be the dll files...)

Comment: Ok, this will work. Once. But what am I going to do when I need to rebuild?

Comment: Although, I guess I could make them readable again as part of some other project that builds before them...

Comment: Ok, this does appear to be working. (by the way, oddly enough, post-build event didn't work on the C++ project itself). Although it does feel uncomfortable, at least for now I have a working build. I guess in the absence of other, "real", answers, this could be the answer to my original question... Tell you what: I'll give you the green checkmark, but only after the bounty expires. Seems fair?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have 2 projects, both dependent on a third. If this isn't true, then you can ignore this whole anwser :)

Because the compiler is threaded, you need to make sure those 2 projects don't try to build before the third is done.

So projectA and projectB both have a dependent build, projectC. projectA starts, sees the output for projectC isn't there and calls Rebuild. While it is building, another compile thread comes along, and it starts to build projectB. It doesn't see the output of projectC(it hasn't finished building yet) so it calls Rebuild, cleaning the project again. Dependent builds are checked at the start of the project, not when they are needed. So if projectB has 4 other projects it has to build before it gets to projectC in it's dependency chain, it might take a while before this second Rebuild is called on projectC.

There are a few ways to solve it.

1. Try to resolve your dependent builds so that projectA relies on projectC. This might not be ideal of course.
2. I think VS2010 still has build order, so you can set which order projects are built in. Not just dependencies. Make sure projectC is listed before both projectA and projectB.
3. The easiest would be to make 2 calls to build. First call `msbuild <project> /target:Clean` then call `msbuild <project> /target:Build` not Rebuild, just Build. That way both projectA and projectB see the output of projectC and don't try to build it.

Comment: It seems very unlikely to me that the creators of MSBuild could ignore the issue of race conditions. But even if that is true, - no, I do not have two projects dependent on the C++ one.

Comment: I thought the same thing, until I saw it for myself. It still wasn't fixed in VS2008, but I haven't had to test it in VS2010 yet. In any case, option 3 might still work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Finding out what is causing it to get built the first time is probably the way to go.  Something is triggering that first build early on even if you remove the reference to it.  Can you post the full msbuild log with /v:diag?  The portion you posted started just *after* the section I was interested in :)

Comment: You have misunderstood my description, I fear. The first build is actually correct. It gets built the first time, because another project depends on it (i.e. "has a reference to it"). It is the second time that should never happen. And even if it does, it shouldn't delete the files - or so I naively think :-)

Comment: And removing the reference does prevent it from being built early on. If I remove the reference, then the C++ project gets build just once. Only it happens **after** the dependent project, which pretty much defeats the whole idea.

Comment: @Fyodor Soikin - Ah yes I misunderstood.  Nevertheless, the full build log is useful to see what targets actually ran as part of the first build of the project.  Targets only run once, which is why the "Build" target does not run in the 2nd pass through the project.  There's something fishy about the first build of the project which makes MSBuild think it has not yet been Cleaned and so comes along and cleans it later.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are building for the right configuration and platform. If you don't specify a platform, it will build with no platform, which is a kind of a `Mixed` platform depending on how the msbuild file is constructed. Visual studio always build with the platform specified in the UI, that might be why it's different from the command line.

If you don't find a solution, maybe a workaround that would work is to create a property based condition that removes whatever is causing the problem in command line (such as building the project twice) and setting the property with /p: from command line.

Comment: Ooooo-kaaaay... And how would the wrong platform cause the files being deleted exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Solution: use a different intermediate directory for each project